# How to create a 3D network-like interactive model?

Tags: unity, 3d

link: [Link to video. it's a small video only 1 min 40 sec](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0wZoqeFxzfRUFR0aDlvdF94NVU/view?usp=sharing) 
I have included a link to the video which shows what I am trying to achieve, I am a beginner and I don't have any idea to do it, also I am using this for something like showing the network I have to people and not for game development, If my question is not clear please comment I will try to clear the problem with my question

Comment: TL;DR: if you are a beginner, start with the beginnings. If its something you can't even break down into smaller tasks, make a note, set it aside, learn some stuff, do other things, and come back later.

Comment: This looks like it would be achievable with some LineRenderers and TextMeshes. What have you tried so far, and where have you run into difficulty?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to generate random location position of items and connect those items with LineRenderer with the help of position. Look for how line are drawing from one point to another in the world space.

Comment: And yeah i have the position of items in 3d coordinates !,So you are saying is that i should learn linerenderer . ?

Comment: @Gautham J I guess yes. And I don't know why my answer is marked as "not useful" but i was just trying to help.